# how to get the function access the other .cpps variables?

Tags: c++, class, external, filestream

I tried to create a small application to get used to fileI/O but I don't know how to get the load()-function in Functions.h to overwrite to variables in main.cpp with the ones in  Functions.h

I save the variables from the main.cpp by using them as parameters in a function.
All fine so far
But when I call the load()-function in the main.cpp it loads the variables from the file and stores them in Functions.h
i could do

```
var = Functions.var;
```

everytime but as this programm is controlled by the user i need a way to do what I wrote above inside of the load()-function.

I hope you understand my problem and may be able to help
im sorry if a similar question was already answered but I didn't find anything helpful when searching but maybe this was just due to me not knowing what to search for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad design if a load function knows too much about other variables. Instead, you should use a function argument. Pass the variable that you want loaded to the load function. That does mean that you need a *reference* parameter:

```
void load(std::string& var) { ... }
```